# White ugly highlighting in VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, highlight

I don't know why it happens but sometimes my code just turns white and its hard to read. Do you know how to get rid of it?

[image: Screenshot]

I tried clicking anywhere else, clicking on it, highlighting it but nothing worked.

Comment: There are no "white highlight" in the image you've added... You may want to add some [hand-drawn circles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385865/where-did-freehand-circles-originate)... And specify what version of VS you use along with any customizations you did and what actions (like search/clicks/...) cause that behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried changing the color theme? Just go to VSCode settings and click color theme. Im not sure if it will help, I don't recall ever encountering the error myself, but its worth a try ig.